# How do I make a USB RS232 dongle show up in /dev/ttyUSB* in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, rs232, dongle

I have a couple of FTDI based USB to Rs232 serial dongles.  Sometimes when I plug them into my Ubuntu 10.04 laptop, they show up as `/dev/ttyUSB0` and `/dev/ttyUSB1`.  Sometimes they don't.  When they don't, sometimes rebooting fixes the problem and sometimes it doesn't.  They always show up in `lsusb` hanging off of Bus 5:

```
...
Bus 005 Device 007: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 005 Device 006: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
...
```

I can see them if I do `ls /dev/bus/usb/005` as `006` and `007`.  But if I pass `/dev/bus/usb/005/006` to `pyserial`, which handles `/dev/ttyUSBx` just fine, I get `SerialException("Could not open port: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/bus/usb/005/006'",)`.

Comment: Have you tried "sudo chmod 666 /dev/bus/005/*"?